# Reading From File To Node in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, readfile

I'm trying to read words and numbers from a file and insert them to Node struct.
There is a file which includes StudentNames and StudentNumbers.
I've created a struct like:

```
struct Node
{
    string Name;
    int Number;
    Node *next;

    Node::Node(){}

    Node::Node(string ID, int No):Name(ID), Number(No){}
};
```

I'm trying to put Names and Numbers directly to Node while creating Node.

```
string filename, line,names;
int nos;
cout<<"Enter Filename: ";
cin >> filename;
ifstream input(filename);

if(input.fail())
{
    cout<<"\n FAILED TO OPEN FILE";
}

else
{
    getline(input, line);
    stringstream  word;
    word>>names
    word>>nos


    Node *p;
    p=new Node(names,nos);
    cout<<p->Name<<p->Number;
}
```

My logic is that it reads words into names because they are string and it reads number parts into nos because nos is int it wont accept string only integers. But it wont names and nos are stay as "" idk how.

This is basically what I'm trying to do. I need to create a linked list with theese node containing names and numbers.

And another problem is I don't get how *next is pointing to the next node.

Sorry if its confusing but I'm confused too :))

Input File Example

```
L0RDQB  12345
LordQb  23456
...
```

Comment: You forgot to init `word` with `line`.

Comment: Your structure combines two separate concepts: 1) a Node containing a Name and Number and 2) a linked list.  Better would be to create two separate data structures each for one purpose.  Also, if you're reading data from a file into a class (or struct), it's often convenient to define an iostream extractor for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second constructor for `Node` that accepts an `istream`:

```
Node::Node(istream &is) { is >> Name >> Number; }
```

I'll leave the eof detection as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It's also worth pondering what should happen if an input file contains only a name but no number.